# How to add specific designed textbox which is of html form on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

How to add specific designed  textbox which is of html form on button click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).appendTo('<div class="fields_wrap">'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="assets/css/consolidation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>




  <title></title>
</head>
<div class="fields_wrap row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="new-input-label-a">
      SELECT bankname
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='dropdown' class="txt-input-dropdown col-xs-2  col-lg-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="Select1" name="dropdown">
                    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <div class="new-input-label">
      FOLIO NUMBERS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-input col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <textarea class="textarea form-control" rows="5" id="fno"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="add" id="addbtn"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have textbox and textarea within a div with class fields_wrap which are designed in html form.

Whenever I click on addbutton then add the class fieldswrap which is having textbox and textarea inside div input_fields_wrap.

But I am not able to add that specific designed div  of html form inside div whenever click on button add.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and have ALL the description in the beginning of the question as I did when I edited your question

Comment: try it like this $(wrapper).appendTo('.fields_wrap');

Answer (score 0):

In the first glance I found 3 problems in your code

1. the first div `<div class="fields_wrap row">` doesn't have closing `</div`
2. add_button and wrapper is already jquery objects but in events you once again pack them inside $ `$(add_button).click(function(e) {` . I don't know whether this is wrong syntax in jquery because I have never tried that :)
3. Most important: your code is not adding a number of boxes which is `< max_fields`. You are actually adding one box again and again. To add more than one box you have to create a hidden box of class `input_fields_wrap` and use `.clone().show().appendTo('<div class="fields_wrap">').`